# Will this graphics card work well for cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hardware

I'm considering buying the GeForce GT 610 2048MB on Amazon for $42.99.

Does this card work well for cycles? Is there a better alternative in the same price range? I want a basic graphics card that will speed up my occasional renders - nothing terribly fancy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on on [hardware recommendations stack exchange](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @brasshat Technically, it's referring to hardware for this specific software.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla, in the [on topic page](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there is a link ;to "What questions should definitely be off topic" on the [meta site](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/). In the answer with more upvotes, item #3 specifies "Hardware specifications, reviews or faults", as off topic, and shows as an example "What is the best processor to run Blender on?". I'll confess that I"m not entirely satisfied with the limitation as it currently exists, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Although with only 48 CUDA cores, it might be rather slow... A slightly better one might be this one:
[MSI GeForce GTX 710](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1234274-REG/msi_gt_710_2gd3h_lp_geforce_gtx_710_graphics.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work, but more is better ;-)

I have a GTX650 and it does pretty well. It will definitely be faster than CPU, probably 2-3 times faster, depending on how many cores you have.

Off-topic, if your budget is $40-50, you can get a 7xx series instead of 6xx from Newegg in that price range ;-)